# fills globl array with 128 random integers and calculates the average sum and displays it

Tags: arrays, mips

```
# seed the generator
# 1 - load the generator ID
# 2 - seed the generator# Generate 128 random numbers (loop)

# 1 - load the generator ID 
# 2 - bound the random number generator to less than or equal to 128
# 3 - generate a random number 
# 4 - store number in array
# 4 - go to step 2 until 128 numbers have been generated# Compute the Average

# 1 - add all the numbers in the array (loop)
# 2 - compute the average (use a right shift)
# 3 - Display the average result message
# 4 - Display the average


    .data 
array: .space 512
genID: .word 1
seed:  .word 1235
prompt: .asciiz "\n the average number generated from the number generator is: "
    .text

.globl main

main:
    lw $a0, genID      #loads genID
    la $t0, seed       #loads seed
    
    lw $a1, 0($t0)
    li $v0, 40          #seed the genrator
    syscall
  
    loop:
        addi $t0, $zero, 0   #init the loop counter 
    la $t8, genID        # load the gen ID
    
    lw $a0, 0($t8)         
    li $a1, 16           #bound gen to less than or equal 128
    li $v0, 42           #gen a random number
    syscall
    la $t7 , array($zero)
    
    sw $a0,array($t0)    #store number in array 
    
    addu $t9,$t9, $a0    #holds running sum of ran nums
    bge $t0, 512, exit   #if t0 equals 512 exit
    
    addi $t0, $t0, 4     #increment index
    j loop               #loops back to step 2
    
    srl $t8, $t9, 7      #slr compute avg
    
      exit:
    li $v0, 4
    la $a0, prompt
    syscall
    
    li $v0, 1
    move $a0, $a1
    syscall
    
    
    li $v0,10
    syscall
```

I'm building a program that fills the globl array with 128 int and calculates the avg. The program complies and runs but doesn't display the avg number. Ive tried reloading the gen thinking it wasn't receiving any numbers but that didn't seem to work. Also tried re writing the loop but nothing. Am I missing something?

Comment: Try to find out where it is going wrong from where you expect.  This is usually done by debugging.  You can single step your program and verify each and every instruction.  If any instruction does not do what you expect then that is where to look.

Comment: will try that. thanks